# how i need to pick values depending upon other values

Tags: oracle

I have a table with data shown below

```
no  s   d
100 I   D
100 C   D
101 C   null
101 I   null
102 C   D
102 I   null
```

then i'm using this query to partition

```
create table pinky nologging as
select no,status,dead
from(select  no,status,dead,
    row_number() over(partition by no order by dead desc) seq
  from PINK) d
where seq = 1;
```

i'm getting this results

```
100 I   D
101 C   null
102 I   null
```

but i want data like shown below

```
100 C D
101 I NULL
102 I NULL
```

i.e,

1. FOR I AND C COMBINATION and both d column is D then pick C
2. FOR I AND C COMBINATION and both d column is null then pick I
3. FOR I AND C COMBINATION and d column is null AND d then pick null corresponding value

Comment: are there always pairs of records with each `no`? or there can be more then two records with some `no`'s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there can be only one `dead is null` record for each `no`:

```
with 
    -- you data, remove it when running the query 
    -- in your environment ...
    pink (no, status, dead) as 
        (select  100, 'I',  'D'  from dual union 
         select  100, 'C',  'D'  from dual union
         select  101, 'C', null  from dual union
         select  101, 'I', null  from dual union
         select  102, 'C',  'D'  from dual union
         select  102, 'I', null  from dual 
    ), 
    -- ... end of you data 
    --
    temp as (   -- a temporary table (CTE) where we make some 
                -- preliminary calculations
        select  pink.*, 
                -- count rows with status = 'I' for this no
                sum(case when status = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by no) ni,
                -- count rows with status = 'C' for this no
                sum(case when status = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by no) nc,
                -- count rows with dead = 'D' for this no
                sum(case when dead   = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by no) nd,
                -- total number of rows (in case it's not always = 2)
                count(*) over(partition by no) n
        from    pink
    )
select  no, status, dead 
from    temp    
where   -- pick 'C' if there's also 'I' and all dead = 'D'
        status = 'C' and ni > 0 and nd = n
        -- pick 'I' if there's also 'C' and all dead is null
   or   status = 'I' and nc > 0 and nd = 0
        -- pick dead is null if there are I's and C's and 
        -- all other dead's = 'D' 
   or   dead is null and ni > 0 and nc > 0 and n - nd = 1;
```